# Syntax error in Update Query

Tags: mysql

I am getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1'
>   error for the following query

```
update Stops set trip_flag = true,
  route_type = (select route_type from Routes 
                where route_id = (select route_id from Trips 
                                  where trip_id = (select trip_id from  Stop_Times
                                                   where stop_id = (select stop_id from Stops where location_type = 0)));
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing closing bracket ) at the end.

Comment: Ya Thanks mPrabhat, but now I am getting a error "ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'Stops' for update in FROM clause"

Answer (score 2):

As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) says:

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

You can workaround this using the multiple-table update syntax and a self-join:

```
UPDATE
       Stops
  JOIN Routes      ON Routes.route_type  = Stops.route_type
  JOIN Trips       ON Trips.route_id     = Routes.route_id
  JOIN Stop_Times  ON Stop_Times.trip_id = Trips.trip_id
  JOIN Stops AS s2 ON s2.stop_id         = Stop_Times.stop_id
SET
  Stops.trip_flag  = TRUE
WHERE
  s2.location_type = 0
```

Comment: @DeepakPawar: I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer some weeks after having accepted it, and instead accepted an answer you previously commented did not work?